# Stuck on Peskin and Schroeder Derivation of Electron Vertex Function

Tags: quantum-field-theory, momentum, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, integration

There are some algebraic steps in Peskin and Schroeder p. 191 that I require help on. In the following, we have the constraints
$$x+y+z=1\qquad\bigwedge\qquad p^2=m^2=k^2\qquad\bigwedge\qquad q^2=0$$
The question is about how they get
$$D=k^2+2k(yq-zp)+yq^2+zp^2-(x+y)m^2=\ell^2-\Delta\tag{6.43}$$
with
$$\ell=k+yq-zp\qquad\bigwedge\qquad\Delta=-xyq^2+(1-z)^2m^2\tag{6.44}$$

---

Following the hint, completing the square yields:
$$\text{LHS}=[k+(yq-zp)]^2-(yq-zp)^2+yq^2+zp^2-(x+y)m^2$$
and so $\ell$ is rather obvious. However, this means that 
$$
\Delta=(yq-zp)^2+yq^2+zp^2-(x+y)m^2\\
=y^2 q^2+z^2 p^2-2yzpq+yq^2+zp^2-(x+y)m^2\\
=z^2m^2-2yzpq+zm^2-(x+y)m^2\\
=(1-z)^2m^2-2yzpq
$$
which is different from the book

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guessing:

I don’t check the Peskin, but I guess some of your constraints are wrong.

What you have to do here is to set the **external** fermion’s momentum to be on-shell, and I guess they are $p$ and $q+p$, i.e. $p^2=m^2$ and $(q+p)^2=m^2$.

If this is true, we will obtain $q\cdot p=-\frac{q^2}{2}$.

Then, we may obtain

\begin{align}
\Delta&=(yq-zp)^2-yq^2-zp^2+(x+y)m^2\\
&=(1-z)^2m^2-y(1-y)q^2-2yzqp\\
&=(1-z)^2m^2-y(1-y)q^2+y(1-y-x)q^2\\
&=(1-z)^2m^2-yxq^2.
\end{align}

Anyway, I strongly recommend you to recheck which momentum is external fermion’s one.

Comment: Great catch! I was just so annoyed and confused because I had to first totally rewrite his question so that I could understand what he was asking. I had already corrected his sign mistakes when I discovered that a big part of why he could not get the answer is precisely because of the persistent sign mistakes. Then I had to work backwards to restore his sign mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I am very certain that you have some of the constraints wrong. If $q^2=0$ then it cannot appear in $\Delta$. We did not use $k^2=m^2$ either.

Also, you have some signs wrong from the very beginning where you wrote down $\Delta$. The correct form of it is really
$$\Delta=(yq-zp)^2-yq^2-zp^2+(x+y)m^2\\
=y(y-1)q^2+z(z-1)(m^2)-2yzqp+(1-z)m^2\\
=(1-z)^2m^2-y(1-y)q^2-2yzqp$$
which is as far as I got.

You should tell us which page and which equation number that is, or at least which chapter and which section, so that it is easier to find what you are talking about.